# Finding fft peaks with scipy and plotting them

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I'm trying to learn how to efficiently use SciPy.

My task is to take a series of audio samples, to plot their fft and try to characterize them finding peaks.

I have the following test program:

```py
import struct
import numpy as np
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def fft_plot(audio, rate):
    n = len(audio)
    T = 1/rate
    yf = scipy.fft.fft(audio)
    z, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(yf, prominence=1)
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(10.0*T), n//10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xf, 10.0/n * np.abs(yf[:n//10]))
    plt.plot(z, 10.0/n * yf[z], "x", color="red")
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("Frequency -->")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    return plt.show()

def get_span(fi):
    b = fi.read(768*4)
    if len(b) < 768*4:
        return None
    r = struct.unpack('768i', b)
    return [float(x/(2**31-1)) for x in r]

with open('/tmp/samples.raw', 'rb') as fi:
    while span := get_span(fi):
        fft_plot(span, 48000)
```

My `samples.raw` file contains a reasonable square wave (440Hz) as integer samples.

[image]

FFT seems reasonable, and also peaks seem in the right place (main one is at 440 and then next is at 1760 and so on, every two octaves as expected).

OTOH finding peaks seems completely wrong both in code:

```
z = [  8  22  36 732 746 760]
```

and in plot.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `np.abs(yf)` instead of `yf` in `find_peaks`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had (at least) two mistakes in my code:

- I did not cut high end of fft (I just avoided plotting it), so peaks were found in the high end of spectrum.
- I forgot to rescale peak plotting.

Here follows a correctly working test script.

```py
import struct
import numpy as np
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

limit = 10

def fft_plot(audio, rate):
    n = len(audio)
    T = 1/rate
    yf = scipy.fft.fft(audio)
    af = np.abs(yf)
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/T, n)
    af = af[:n // limit]
    xf = xf[:n // limit]
    z, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(af, prominence=1)
    plt.plot(xf, af)
    plt.plot(xf[z], af[z], "x", color="red")
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("Frequency -->")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    return plt.show()

def get_span(fi):
    b = fi.read(768*4)
    if len(b) < 768*4:
        return None
    r = struct.unpack('768i', b)
    return [float(x/(2**31-1)) for x in r]

with open('/tmp/samples.raw', 'rb') as fi:
    while span := get_span(fi):
        fft_plot(span, 48000)
```

I still have problem to correctly limit `find_peaks()` to get meaningful peaks (i would like to have at least the first 4), but that is another issue.

[image]